# jboss eap 7 - javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, jboss

Me encuentro migrando de *jboss 6* a *7*, he seguido los pasos que indica la gente de *redhat* en su página, también he utilizado *windup* como herramienta para ver conflictos en mi aplicación que pueden darse al pasar de una version de *jboss* a la otra.

Al parecer todo compila bien, sin embargo al levantar el *jboss 7* me aparece el siguiente error:

```
13:55:39,415 ERROR [Proyectik] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) : javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:app/sistema-hospitalario-app/DataServiceImpl
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106) [wildfly-naming-7.0.0.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.GA-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207) [wildfly-naming-7.0.0.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.GA-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:235) [wildfly-naming-7.0.0.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.GA-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:193) [wildfly-naming-7.0.0.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.GA-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:189) [wildfly-naming-7.0.0.GA-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.GA-redhat-2]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
at ec.com.hdlv.sishos.app.factory.SistemaHospitalarioFactory.getDataService(SistemaHospitalarioFactory.java:278) [sistema-hospitalario-app-1.0.0.jar:]
at ec.com.hdlv.sishos.app.utiles.CatalogoUtil.getCatalogoByNombreCatalogoPadreByCodigoInterno(CatalogoUtil.java:59) [sistema-hospitalario-app-1.0.0.jar:]
at ec.com.hdlv.sishos.app.enumeracion.EstadioEnum.<init>(EstadioEnum.java:16) [sistema-hospitalario-app-1.0.0.jar:]
at ec.com.hdlv.sishos.app.enumeracion.EstadioEnum.<clinit>(EstadioEnum.java:9) [sistema-hospitalario-app-1.0.0.jar:]
```

Lo que me llama la atención es que el nombre del *EJB* **java:app/sistema-hospitalario-app/DataServiceImpl** si está listado al levantar el *jboss* unas líneas antes, e incluso lo puedo ver desde el árbol `jndi` en la consola de administración:

```
09:52:55,337 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'DataServiceImpl' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "sistema-hospitalario-app-1.0.0.jar" of deployment "sistema-hospitalario-ear.ear"' are as follows:

java:global/sistema-hospitalario-ear/sistema-hospitalario-app/DataServiceImpl!ec.com.hdlv.utilitario.dao.commons.service.DataService
java:app/sistema-hospitalario-app/DataServiceImpl!ec.com.hdlv.utilitario.dao.commons.service.DataService
java:module/DataServiceImpl!ec.com.hdlv.utilitario.dao.commons.service.DataService
java:global/sistema-hospitalario-ear/sistema-hospitalario-app/DataServiceImpl
java:app/sistema-hospitalario-app/DataServiceImpl
java:module/DataServiceImpl
```

No sé por qué se da este error, ¿hay algo que me falta en la configuración?

La aplicación a desplegar es un `EAR` que tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
EAR
JAR (EJB 3)
WAR (JSF)
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar le agradecería mucho.

Comment: Podrías colocar los .xml de configuración?

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar, me puedes indicar cuales serían los que necesitas, son un tanto nuevo en esto de jboss? supongo que el web.xml sería uno de ellos, pero hay otros muchos